# How to manage different weight units at the product level in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-fields

In my WooCommerce website is an e-commerce website, some products have a weight Unit in "Kg", some others in "Liter", and Some are in "Pound". In WooCommerce, I can choose a unique unit for Weight. I want it to write a Unit manually by typing Like 5 Liters or 5 Kg or 5 Pounds.

Here is the Screenshot reference:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to add an additional field (radio buttons) in the admin product pages next to the weight field *(on the shipping tab settings)*, to **manage different weight units** at the product level.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
// Add custom fields to product shipping tab
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_dimensions', 'add_product_weight_unit_option');
function add_product_weight_unit_option(){
    global $product_object;

    $weight_unit = $product_object->get_meta('_weight_unit');

    woocommerce_wp_radio(
        array(
            'id'          => '_weight_unit',
            'label'       => __( 'Weight unit', 'woocommerce' ),
            'options'     => array(
                'Kg'        => __( 'Kg (default)', 'woocommerce' ),
                'Litre'     => __( 'Litre', 'woocommerce' ),
                'Pound'     => _x( 'Pound', 'Tax status', 'woocommerce' ),
            ),
            'value'       => $weight_unit ? $weight_unit : 'Kg',
        )
    );
}

// Save custom fields to product shipping tab
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_google_meet_link_custom_field');
function save_google_meet_link_custom_field( $product ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['_weight']) && ! empty($_POST['_weight']) && isset($_POST['_weight_unit']) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( '_weight_unit', esc_attr($_POST['_weight_unit']) );
    } 
}

// Formating weight with the weight different weight ubits
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_weight', 'custom_format_weight', 20, 2 );
function custom_format_weight( $weight_string, $weight ){
    $weight_string  = wc_format_localized_decimal( $weight );

    if ( ! empty( $weight_string ) ) {
        $weight_label = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_weight_unit', true );

        $weight_string = sprintf(
            _nx( '%1$s  %2$s', '%1$s  %2$s'.'s', $weight, 'formatted weight', 'woocommerce' ),
            $weight_string,
            $weight_label ? $weight_label : get_option( 'woocommerce_weight_unit' ),
        );
    } else {
        $weight_string = __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    return $weight_string;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for providing me with a proper solution. Now I'm facing another problem with Unit Label on Invoice, It's showing Kg by default instead of showing different unit labels like 200gm which should be shown the same on the invoice but it's showing 200Kg instead of 200gm.

Comment: I have already accepted the answer.

Comment: Oups that's right, yes :)